# unexpected result of CATransform3D animation

Tags: ios, animation, catransform3d

This is the hierarchy of my views.
[image: Roullete's super view is transformView]

When I run this code, it show's following output.
[image: Description]

But when I tried to transformView at z-axis it shows unexpected result as follows
[image: Misbehave]

The code of transformation at z-axis is as follows

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = -1 / 500.0;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(50), 1, 0, 0);
self.transformView.layer.transform = transform;
```

Comment: I guess here you require scaling as well, because when you rotate circle on z axis it will look a like sphere type. I am not sure, but just give a try with transformation group (Scaling + Rotating) both.

Comment: If the problem is clipping of the upper part, it's because both of them are at the sam z-position (like in this snapshot http://tinypic.com/r/x2lco0/8), you can try moving your transformView layer towards you in the z-axis. It won't affect the display but will fix the hierarchy. Try adding another transform after the last line, e.g. 
self.transformView.layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(self.transformView.layer.transform, 0.0, 0.0, 100); 
to bring it 100 px forward or send background image view backward.